# Creating List Columns with pnp/sp not being created

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

So I can create a list just with ensure:

```
sp.web.lists.ensure(list)
    .then((ler: ListEnsureResult) => {

        if (ler.created) {
            console.log(list, " was created; creating column");

            ler.list.fields.addText("myTestColumn");
        }
        return ler.created;
    });
```

But is not creating a column.

I have also tried code samples from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233603/creating-list-with-columns-in-spfx-is-failing-for-few-columns) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts), neither of which have worked.

Comment: your code works fine. Go to your list settings, the column will be present there.

Comment: So it adds a column to the site, not to the list?  How do I add a column to a list then?

Comment: no, it adds column to the list only. Go to the created list and then click on the list settings from the gear icon in top right section, you will find the column there :)

Comment: Ha!  You're right!  Thank you!  Any idea how to get the columns to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your code is working fine.

Its just that the column is not visible in the List View. It is already created in the List and is visible when we check the list settings page or try to create a new list item.

So, now you need to add the column to the default list view. For that, you just need to make additional REST API call to make it visible in the default list view as below:

```
sp.web.lists.ensure(list)
    .then((ler: ListEnsureResult) => {

        if (ler.created) {
            console.log(list, " was created; creating column");

            ler.list.fields.addText("myTestColumn").then(function(){

                const view = ler.list.defaultView;

                view.fields.add("myTestColumn");

          });           

        }
        return ler.created;
    });
```